# Spring Faces Error faces:flow-builder-services

Tags: java, spring, myfaces

I have this `Java web app` running on `spring framework with web flow`.

I tried integrating it with **spring faces** but I get this **error** in my config file:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "flow" for element
>   "flow:flow-executor" is not bound.

**Here's the stack trace**

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "flow" for element
>   "flow:flow-executor" is not bound.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:
>   123)  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:615)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:706)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:677)
>   at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:56)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267) 
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly specify the name space prefix `flow:` in your XML configuration file preferably on root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<....  
     xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-1.0.xsd"
```